# Linear system of 2 ODE's with complex eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, parametric

This is a two-part question:

1) Suppose we have the eigenvalues $λ_1 = a + bi$, $λ_2 = a - bi$. Then, is it true that:

For $a>0,$ the phase portrait is a spiral out

For $a<0$, the phase portrait is a spiral in

For $a=0$, the phase portrait is a closed loop (stable center, like a circle, an ellipse etc.)

2) By solving a system, I arrived at the parametric equations $x(t) = 10\sin(2t), 
y(t) = 4\cos(2t) + 2\sin(2t)$.

The solution shows that this figure is a skewed ellipse, but can someone explain how I could derive this from the parametric equations (and maybe even find the equation of the ellipse in terms of $x,y$), given that I have not learned the general equation for a skewed ellipse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the Cartesian equation, notice $\frac{1}{4}\left(y-\frac{x}{5}\right)=\cos(2t)$ and $\frac{x}{10}=\sin(2t)$ so 
$$\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2+\frac{1}{16}\left(y-\frac{x}{5}\right)^2=1.$$
Making a change of variables $X=x$ and $Y=y-\frac{x}{5}$ we have
$$\frac{X^2}{100}+\frac{Y^2}{16}=1,$$
which is the equation of an ellipse.

It is a skewed ellipse since one of its axes is $Y=0$, i.e. $y=\frac{x}{5}$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! If I can ask another quick question, another problem gave me the parametric equations $x(t)=cos(4t)+sin(4t), y(t)=sin(4t)$. We notice $x-y=cos(4t),y=sin(4t)$, so the equation becomes $(x-y)^2 +y^2 = 1$. I think this is another ellipse, whose major axis is x=y, but how can I derive the radii a,b, since the denominators in the latter equation are both 1? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually found the answer before reading the comment, by substituting $t=π/16$ in the parametric equation for x and finding $x=sqrt(2)$, when clearly y ranges from $-1$ to $1$, but your answer provided very helpful insight!

Comment: @JBuck I don't think it's easy to find these. You could use a matrix transformation (rotate) or use calculus but I don't know a quick way.

Comment: This is what WA gives: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-y%29%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1+semimajor+axis+length

Comment: Oh I see. However, I used the fact that x takes its maximum value = sqrt(2) for 4t=π/4, and its minimum value = -sqrt(2) for 4t=-π/4. So clearly x is between -sqrt(2) and  sqrt(2), y is between -1 and 1 and therefore the x-radius is sqrt(2) and the y-radius is 1.

Comment: These are the right limits for $x$ and $y$, but I believe the semimajor and semiminor radii are the greatest and least distances from the centre to any point on the ellipse, which for a skewed ellipse are not the same.